# Google Oauth callback outside of app domain in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, localhost, google-oauth

I encountered an issue recently when trying to add Google OAuth authentication to the admin of my app.

Our dev team works in a docker environment with a few different project containers all communicating together. All the URLs are rewritten to help us keep track of the different containers instead of having multiple `localhost:XXXX` to remember with modifications to our `/etc/hosts`

So after spinning up our dev environment, we work on URLs such as :

- admin.project.local
- api.project.local
- angular-app1.project.local
- angular-app2.project.local
- etc...

So onto the issue : when setting up Google Oauth, I have to add a callback to my backend meaning the callback URL will be something like `https://admin.project.local/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`.

That's where the issue lies : The Google OAuth callback [validations rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation) prevents us from redirecting to our local domain `admin.project.local`. So we get an 400 error when logging.

I've tried using `localhost:3000` as the callback URL and it works (cf the above validation rules).

I'm guessing we won't be able to override Google validation rules so the solution would be to override the callback URL set by `devise` to something like `https://redirectmeto.com/<callback url>` but I couldn't find how.

Comment: Check out https://ngrok.com/ - there's a section on testing APIs, etc.